# Devexpress RichEditDocumentServer HtmlText property not properly formatting CSS (width, padding, margin) .NET Framework 4.7.2

Tags: c#, html, css, devexpress, html-to-pdf

Having an issue where I'm using DevExpress RichEditDocument server and the .HtmlText property being used to convert HTML to a PDF document. The base html and some styles get applied, however styles like width, padding, margins are not being applied. I have tried putting the styles in the HTML tags and using a separate style tag with classes as well.

Are there adjustments I can make to the DevExpress page itself for margins so the HTML will start at the edge of the PDF?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, what is your project type, WinForm or WPF ?

Comment: It's an API running on the backend

Comment: @AliBigdeli API via WebAPI that returns the generated PDF as HTTPResponseMessage and within that the pdf is the content a byte array

Answer (score 0):

To setup page margins you can use [`Section.Margins`](https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.API.Native.Section.Margins) property of a document:

```
document.Sections[0].Margins.Top = 0;
document.Sections[0].Margins.Bottom = 0;
document.Sections[0].Margins.Left = 0.2f;
document.Sections[0].Margins.Right = 0.2f;
```

Full example is shown on DevExpress documentation page: https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/402993/word-processing-document-api/html-import-and-export?p=netstandard#example-1-convert-html-to-pdf

*PS:* HTML support in `RichEditDocumentServer` appears to be very limited. All supported/unsupported tags with attributes are listed here: https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/15684/word-processing-document-api/html-import-and-export/html-support-limitations